# How to enable or disable a Polly Policy at run-time?

Tags: c#, polly

In the definition of a policy, I'd like to be able to disable or enable the policy at run-time, versus doing it in the call site, since I may have multiple call sites.

This is my approach so far?

```
private RetryPolicy<IDisposable> GetRetryPolicy()
{
    if (!this.config.DistributedLockEnabled)
    {
        NoOpPolicy<IDisposable> policy = Policy.NoOp<IDisposable>();
        return policy;
    }

    RetryPolicy<IDisposable> lockPolicy = Policy
        .Handle<TimeoutException>()
        .OrResult<IDisposable>(d => d == null)
        .WaitAndRetry(
            this.config.WorkflowLockHandleRequestRetryAttempts,
            attempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(this.config.WorkflowLockHandleRequestRetryMultiplier * Math.Pow(this.config.WorkflowLockHandleRequestRetryBase, attempt)),
            (delegateResult, calculatedWaitDuration, attempt, context) =>
                {
                    if (delegateResult.Exception != null)
                    {
                        this.logger.Information(
                            "Exception {0} attempt {1} delaying for {2}ms",
                            delegateResult.Exception.Message,
                            attempt,
                            calculatedWaitDuration.TotalMilliseconds);
                    }
                });
    return lockPolicy;
}
```

But alas, this does not compile :)

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 5):

You could return a Policy like this:

```
private static Policy GetRetryPolicy(bool useWaitAndRetry)
    {
        if (!useWaitAndRetry)
        {
            return Policy.NoOp();
        }

        return Policy
            .Handle<Exception>()
            .WaitAndRetry(new[]
            {
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)
            });
    }
```

This use it like this:

```
GetRetryPolicy(true).Execute(() =>
            {
                // Process the task here
            });
```

Comment: I think you were on to something by returning the abstract Policy. Please fix the code and I will accept your answer

Comment: x-ref also discussion at https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/634 . Returning the policy as an interface is also an option: `private ISyncPolicy<IDisposable> GetRetryPolicy()  { ... }`

Comment: @StephenPatten What is wrong with the code? This compiles fine with Polly V7.2.3